# Converting app for iPhone 3Gs and iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

Need advice.

I developed an app that is only meant for the iPhone. I also developed the app's look an feel for iPhone 5 and above (bigger screens).

I submitted my app and Apple is saying I have to have it compatible with iPhone 3Gs and iPad.

Seems like this is going to take significant work for an app that is not meant to run on an iPad and for obsolete iPhones.

Has anyone run into this before. Is there a way to get around this? Is there a simple way to convert iPhone 5 and beyond views to 3Gs and iPad?

Thanks.

Reply from apple:

```
Hello,

Thank you for your response. In order to bring your app into compliance 
with our guidelines it would be appropriate for your app to have 
complete functionality on iPad at 2X iPhone 3Gs resolution per our 2.10 
guideline. Please address this issue upon submitting your new binary.

Best regards,
App Store Review
```

Comment: What is the lowest version of iOS you support ?

Comment: This is my first app so bear with me. My Deployment Target is 8.0, Devices is iPhone.

Comment: Can you show us the exact message you received from apple ?

Comment: post updated with reply from apple

Comment: This is what I thought, it has nothing to do with iPhone 3Gs. However even iPhone apps are required to work on iPads by Apple. Usually, they just work out of the box on iPads and you have nothing to do. So what exactly doesn't work on iPads for your app ?

Comment: iPhone3gs to iPhone4s and iPad 2 are too "zoomed" in that content get cut off at the bottom and sides. All the text boxes are also huge. I did all my view development on an iPhone 5 and tested it on iPhone5s and above in the simulator.

Comment: Well since iOS 8 works on iPhone 4S, you have to support iPhone 4S screen size (which is the screen size used on iPads). I'm sorry, but there is no way to get out of this. Apple will not publish your app if it doesn't work on all iPhone models that they support with their latest OS (currently : iOS 9 and iPhone 4S)

Comment: Dang. It is going to take alot of work to make this app work on iPhone4s and that is a very obsolete phone. 

I read somewhere that you can make your app 64-bit only and that will make it iPhone5 and above. Do you know about this?

Comment: iPhone 4S may be old but it's not as obsolete as you think. A lot of people still have one. And that's probably why Apple is still supporting this model even with iOS 9. As for the 64bit thing, never heard of it, but you might be right, you should check it out.

Comment: thanks for the info and time deadbeef!